Объект DelegateCommand не может быть преобразован в переменную типа ICommand
Изучаю паттерн MVVM, и столкнулся с проблемой в классе ViewModel. Информацию я беру с этой статьи: https://intellitect.com/blog/getting-started-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-pattern-using-windows-presentation-framework-wpf/.
В статье класс ViewModel содержит поля типа DelegateCommand и ICommand:
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly DelegateCommand _changeNameCommand;
    public ICommand ChangeNameCommand => _changeNameCommand;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _changeNameCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnChangeName, CanChangeName);
    }
    ...
}

Но у меня возникает ошибка с преобразованием _changeNameCommand в переменную ChangeNameCommand. Пишет:

Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "MVVM.ViewModel.DelegateCommand" в "System.Windows.Input.ICommand". Существует явное преобразование(возможно, пропущено приведение типов)

Хорошо, делаю явное приведение:
public ICommand ChangeNameCommand => (ICommand)_changeNameCommand;
Но после этого среда начинает ругаться на вот эту строку в конструкторе:
_changeNameCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnChangeName, CanChangeName);
Пишет, что:

DelegateCommand не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 2.

Хотя конструктор с двумя параметрами для DelegateCommand определен. Более того, вопросы возникают еще на стадии, когда среда начинает требовать явное приведение DelegateCommand к ICommand. Ведь DeelegateCommand реализует этот интерфейс.
Вот мой код DelegateCommand:
public class DelagateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _executeAction;                                            
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecuteAction;

    public DelagateCommand(Action<object> executeAction) : this(executeAction, null)
    {
        _executeAction = executeAction;
    }
    public DelagateCommand(Action<object> executeAction, Predicate<object> CanExecuteAction)
    {
        _executeAction = executeAction;
        _canExecuteAction = CanExecuteAction;
    }
    public void InvokeCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    public void Execute(object parametr) { _executeAction(parametr); }
    public bool CanExecute(object parametr) => _canExecuteAction?.Invoke(parametr) ?? true; //все, что является делегатом можно запустить. Тут мы запускаем проверку на возможность выполнения команды
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

}

Все классы описаны буквально так же, как в статье.

Слишком мудрите. Привязка доступна к публичным свойствам, у которых есть хотяб get, вот и делайте просто свойство с get, в вашем случае это public ICommand ChangeNameCommand { get; }, все, ничего больше не нужно. В конструкторе уже пишите ChangeNameCommand = new DelegateCommand(...);, все.

@EvgeniyZ я пытался делать что-то похожее. Но, как и в случае того, что вы написали, ошибка все та же: либо не получается преобразовать из DelegateCommand в ICommand, либо нет такого конструктора

У Вас опечатка в имени класса public class DelagateCommand : ICommand

проблема была решена. спасибо всем, кто отвечал. Проблема была в том, что DelegateCommand и ViewModel находились в разных папках в проекте, и при попытке использование DelegateCommand в классе модели представления, среда сама создала описание этого класса в той же папке, что и модель представления. Либо я непонятно куда нажал, что это произошло, но один итог - я этого не заметил и промучался, хотя среда просто не видела нужное описание из-за перекрытия пространства имен
